# JOLT transformation filter only one field

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Looking for some help with JOLT transformation, to which I am completely new.

my input JSON looks like this

```json
{
  "type": "delete",
  "timestamp": 1681484884000,
  "binlog_filename": "bin.000003",
  "binlog_position": 6378700,
  "database": "db1",
  "table_name": "records",
  "table_id": 108,
  "columns": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "id",
      "column_type": 4,
      "value": 259
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "index_id",
      "column_type": 4,
      "value": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "state_id",
      "column_type": 4,
      "value": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

(This is from mysql binlogs.)

I want to transform it to have a single field from the "columns" array..

```json
[
  {
    "id": 259
  }
]
```

from one of the tutorials in cloudera community, i saw this JOLT transformation.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "@(value)": "[#1].@(1,name)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it gives all fileds..  I just need one filed which is the **`id`**. I need to drop rest all fields..

Can someone please help in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more transformation and make it the following

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "@value": "@name" // match directly as they're from the same level
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "[0].&" // [0] produces a square-bracket wrapper
    }
  }
]
```

which filters out by `id` attribute

or shorter option would be

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "columns": {
        "*": {
          "name": {
            "id": { // conditional to check the exact literal "id" which's one of the values of "name"
              "@2,value": "[].&1" // go 2 levels up the tree to get the valoe of the "value"
                                  // go 1 level up the tree to copy the "id" key, []
                                  // produces a square-bracket wrapper by using []
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```